# How can I get the value from a cell when clicking other cell in the row?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where I make a table from php deploying the result of a previous query. It shows the ID in the first column. I want to have some colums clickable to edit the value, changing it in the database and refreshing the page. For that it appears a Bootstrap modal when you click the link columns (the ones with ). When you fill the modal it sends the information to a JQuery script that calls a php page via AJAX. That php page can be called asynchronously to edit the value in the database and it requires the new value and the ID of the row to make the UPDATE SQL statement.

I need to send the ID of the row you click to the JQuery method that uses AJAX. But in the moment i call the function, i don't know how to send the ID as parameter.

I have tried to find the ID of the row you click by touching the DOM vía JQuery adding ids to the rows but it's just too complicate for my level.

This is where php deploys the table with the information.

```
$resISDEFE = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM personal_isdefe WHERE proyecto=".$idProyecto);
        if($resISDEFE->num_rows>0){
                $index=0;
                while($isdefe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resISDEFE)){
                    $resCategoria = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM categoria_isdefe WHERE id=".$isdefe['categoria']);
                    $categoria = $resCategoria->fetch_row();
                    $idISDEFE = $isdefe['id']; <-- I save the row's ID here -->
                    echo "<tr id='isdefe'>";
                    echo "<td><p>".$idISDEFE."</p></td>";
                    echo "<td><p>".$categoria[1]."</p></td>";
                    echo "<td><p>".$isdefe['edg']."</p></td>";
                    echo "<td><p><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalConcepto'>".$isdefe['porcentaje']."%</a></p></td>";
                    echo "<td><p>".$isdefe['horas_contratadas']."</p></td>";
                    $importe_prestacion = $isdefe['horas_contratadas'] * $categoria[2];
                    echo "<td><p>".number_format($importe_prestacion,2,",",".")." €</p></td>";

                    echo "<td><p>".number_format(($isdefe['importe_variable']+$importe_prestacion),2,",",".")." €</p></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";


                }
```

This is the modal it appears.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalConcepto" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Editar concepto</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="newConcepto"></textarea><br>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick='editConcepto(<?php $idISDEFE ?>)'>Guardar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JQuery method that is called when you click "Guardar".

```
function newConcepto(id, newConcepto){
        if(newConcepto!=""){
            $.get("ajax/editarConceptoISDEFE.php?id="+id+"&con="+newConcepto, function(data){
                    if(data=="1"){
                        var time = setTimeout(function(){
                            location.reload();
                        },500);
                    }
                    else alert("Error al actualizar el concepto");
            });
        }
}

function editConcepto(id){
    var newConcepto = $('#newConcepto').val();
    newConcepto(id,newConcepto);
}
        }
```

The expected result is that when the page is reloaded, you could see the changed value exactly in the row you clicked before.

Comment: As a side-note, I generally recommend that you return results from php in the form of JSON that gets set into a DOM structure with javascript. I only say this because it looks like you're echoing a lot of html.

Comment: @GrantNoe I only use the echos to deploy the result tables of the querys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on in this question, but I'm going to give it a shot and you can steer me in a different direction if this isn't what you're looking for.

### How to get the value of another cell in a row with jQuery

Wrap the cell you want to get in some sort of identifier span or div (in my example it's `.span-of-other-cell`). Use the jQuery `.closest` function to get the "row," and then use `.find` to locate your identifier and its value:

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-cell', function () {
   var id = $(this).closest('.table-row').find('.span-of-other-cell').val();
});
```

**Some helpful links:**

`.closest`: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

`.find`: https://api.jquery.com/find/

### How I personally store IDs for later use

I use html's `data-` prefix for element attributes.

```html
<div data-id="12345"></div>
```

If you add a `data-` attribute to your row, the javascript above is simplified, and the ID visually hidden (though easy to access for anybody with basic browser skills, so this is not meant to obfuscate or be secure if needed):

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-cell', function () {
   var id = $(this).closest('.table-row').attr('data-id');
});
```

**Let me know if this helps**, or if I misunderstood and need to go a different direction with my answer.

### As for passing the ID back as a parameter...

This really depends upon your goals. If the ID doesn't need to be secure (and it sounds like it's displayed in a table, so in no need of being secured), then you could just pass it back to PHP with AJAX using the GET protocol:

```
// assume that var "id" is accessible from this ajax function
$.ajax({
   url: "script.php?id=" + id
});
```